# Не проходит пинг

Tags: linux, iptables, archlinux

Постаивл с помощью `yaourt -S linux-pae` PAE ядро версии 4.9(немного поправил PKGBUILD). Собиралось ядро из под 4.7-PAE и соответственно у меня был выбор какие новые фитчи включить, а какие выключить. ЧТо я там выбирал уже не помню, но пинг теперь не проходит.
Привожу состояние iptables

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 367 packets, 71387 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere            
 2612  752K ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:ACK/ACK
  149 19533 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             state ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:domain dpts:1024:65535
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-reply
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp destination-unreachable
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp source-quench
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp time-exceeded
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp parameter-problem
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp multiport dports http,https,http-alt,vcom-tunnel
    3   180 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     {IP адрес андроид устройства}  anywhere
```

Проверял пинг с помощью http://www.wservice.info/
У меня настроено соеденение IPv6 через Miredo. Так же не работает пинг, но еще и достучатся до 80(443 и тд) порта невозможно, холтя с стороны IPv4, localhost IPv6 доступ есть.
Состояние ip6tables

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 17 packets, 2560 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all      lo     any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp      any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:ACK/ACK
    0     0 ACCEPT     all      any    any     anywhere             anywhere             state ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all      any    any     anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp      any    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:domain dpts:1024:65535
    0     0 ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp echo-reply
    0     0 ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp echo-request
    0     0 ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp destination-unreachable
    0     0 ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp time-exceeded
    0     0 ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp parameter-problem
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp      any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp multiport dports http,https,http-alt,vcom-tunnel

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 28 packets, 3164 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Собственно, в чем причина? И как это можно исправить?
UPD: На стаандартном 4.9 ядре(не PAE) тоже не работает.

Comment: пересобрать linux, но уже внимательно и вдумчиво подойти к процессу включения новой функциональности. если «не поможет», сообщить в соответствующую рассылку.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin зашел в стандартное ядро 4.9, ситуация аналогична. О какой "рассылке" Вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: не знаю, конечно, что именно вы подразумеваете под словосочетанием «стандартный linux 4.9». если «сконфигурирован и собран не вами», то пишите в первую очередь тому, кто конфигурировал/собирал.

Comment: сохрани правила, удали все. добавь по очереди и проверяй что ломает